# Translate Prechat page for Live Agent Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, liveagent, translation, chat

I have created custom labels for the prechat page for live agent chat in Salesforce and maintained the translations. What parameter can I use on the VF page to drive the correct language translation based on the chat button configuration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the "language" parameter to your page tag.

```
<apex:page language="xx">
```

You could populate the value of the 'xx' with something you query from the user, or a URL parameter from the site, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to this by accessing the language corresponding to the chat button via the url that SF builds.

```
var languageMatcher = new RegExp("language=(.{2})");
var language = languageMatcher.exec( decodeURIComponent( document.location ) )[1];
```